# Quando usare "tra" e quando "di" dopo "scontro" o "scontri"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

Cercando [informazioni sulla parola "scontro" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scontro/), ho trovato che si può usare sia con la preposizione "tra" sia con la preposizione "di". Per esempio:

> - Scontri *tra* Romani e Cartaginesi
> - Lo scontro fisico *delle* due opposte fazioni di studenti.

Non riesco a capire però quando si debba usare una o l'altra preposizione. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In linea di massima, direi che quando c'è `tra` si tratta *quasi sempre* di un complemento di relazione e quando c'è `di/...` si tratta *molto spesso* di un complemento di specificazione. Sicuramente c'è una zona grigia nella quale si concentrano i miei (e i tuoi) dubbi.

Scontri `tra Romani e Cartaginesi` è complemento di relazione, mentre uno scontro `di civiltà` e lo scontro `di Roncisvalle` sono complementi di specificazione. Lo scontro `di Giulia e Giovanna` mi lascia perplesso. Benché introdotto da `di` potrebbe essere considerato complemento di relazione, ma se lo vediamo come lo scontro di Giulia e Giovanna nel senso di *quello scontro in particolare* invece di quell'altro, si potrebbe dire che è complemento di specificazione.

Sono sicuro che `c'è stato uno scontro di Giulia e Giovanna` **non va assolutamente bene**, ma Josh61 in una replica a un mio commento ha sottolineato come `Lo scontro di Giulia e Giovanna è stato molto sgradevole` invece sia assolutamente corretto.

Direi che sia il caso di andare per esempi:

- C'è stato uno scontro *tra* Giulia e Giovanna
- <s>C'è stato **uno** scontro *di* Giulia e Giovanna</s>
- Lo scontro *tra* Giulia e Giovanna è stato molto
  sgradevole
- Lo scontro *di* Giulia e Giovanna è stato sgradevole
- Lo scontro *di* Roncisvalle (qui non ti sogneresti mai di mettere `tra`)

Espressioni idiomatiche in cui `di` e `tra` andrebbero entrambi bene ma si preferisce uno dei due perché l'espressione si è cristallizzata così:

- scontro `di` civiltà
- scontro `tra` titani

Comment: ma anche *scontro di Titani*.

Comment: Sì, ho controllato. Non lo direi mai neanche sotto tortura, ma Google mi contraddice impietosamente.

Comment: Purtroppo qui il è difficile dare regole, per questo ho scritto 'generalmente'. Mi rendo conto che per uno straniero risulti difficile. Probabilmente usare 'tra' è più comune tranne quando si specifica il luogo.

Comment: Più che "il luogo" direi "qualsiasi altra cosa". Uno può dire "lo scontro di ieri". L'unica zona grigia per me è quando ci sono più entità e lo scontro è `tra` o `di` quelle entità. Allora la faccenda diventa interessante.

Comment: Direi entrambi. Lo scontro tra le classi delle medie, lo scontro delle classi delle medie.

Comment: Eh, ma non sempre! Per esempio `uno scontro di X e Y` non va bene per niente, cosa sulla quale abbiamo già concordato

Comment: Uno scontro tra le classi, uno scontro delle classi....non suona male.

Comment: Tu diresti davvero `ieri c'è stato uno scontro delle classi delle medie`? Forse `lo`, se lo abbiamo già nominato e ci stiamo riferendo a quello in particolare.

Comment: Probabilmente direi 'tra', ma 'di' non suona male come nel primo caso. Perlomeno al mio orecchio.

Comment: Ho assistito ad uno scontro delle classi della scuola media.... No?

Comment: In effetti sì, anche se mai e poi mai lo direi. Possiamo dire con assoluta certezza che `c'è stato uno scontro di Giovanna e Carla` è abbastanza inascoltabile e tutto il resto è opinabile, sia io che te preferiamo comunque `tra`, ma tu tolleri `di` molto più di me

Comment: Mi chiedo se siamo stati d'aiuto a Charo!!

Comment: Non lo so, ma non vorrei essere al suo posto.

Comment: In ogni caso, quando si decide per “relazione”, meglio evitare lo scontro  fra “scontro” e “tra”: “fra” è il sostituto da preferire.

Comment: Aggiungo un “voto” soggettivo, a orecchio, a favore di “tra/fra” e contro “di” in casi come lo scontro fra titani, fra classi e fra Giovanna e Carla. In particolare, “lo scontro di Giovanna e Carla” mi lascerebbe il dubbio che G. e C. costituissero insieme una delle parti di uno scontro (contro una terza persona o un macigno).

Answer (score 1):

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scontro%20tra%2Cscontro%20di%2C%20scontro%20dei%2C%20scontro%20delle&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscontro%20tra%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscontro%20di%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscontro%20dei%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscontro%20delle%3B%2Cc0) ***scontro tra vs scontro di***

Per indicare uno scontro che coinvolge due  più entità generalmente sono  entrambi corretti.

- Uno scontro tra rivali, uno scontro di rivali.

La preposizione ***di*** si usa per definire il tipo/luogo di scontro:

- Lo scontro di Roncisvalle.

(Vedi anche i vari esempi in Ngram.)

Comment: Ma non si può dire `c'è stato uno scontro di Giulia e Giovanna`.

Comment: No, in quel caso suona meglio  *tra Giulia e Giovanna,*  ma puoi dire: *Lo scontro di Giulia e Giovanna è stato molto sgradevole.*

Comment: Hai ragione....